# How to test a DataTables server-processing sourced table with Watin?

Tags: c#, jquery, testing, datatables, watin

I have a DataTables-controlled table which sources its data via [server-side processing](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side). I want to test with Watin that this table contains certain rows, but when the page is initially loaded, the table hasn't yet been populated (as the DataTables script is loading data from the server). How can I in my test wait until DataTables has finished loading data from the server, before I check the table rows?

Comment: Give us some html code before and after it's loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest polling the DOM until the sub elements are present.  If you have a static data set coming back you can wait until the table has the right number of rows returned.  Once you are sure that the data is populated you can move onto the next part of your step.  I just included the numbers as examples.

```
public void CheckForCells()
{
    Table table = Document.Table(Find.ById("MyTableID"));

    int counter = 0;
    while (table.TableRows.Count < 5 && counter < 50)
    {
        table.Refresh();
        counter++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

}
```